# Adding a prefix to all array elements in Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I am storing command line parameters in an array variable. (This is necessary for me).
I wanted to prefix all the array values with a string passing through a variable.

```
PREFIX="rajiv"

services=$( echo $* | tr -d '/' )

echo  "${services[@]/#/$PREFIX-}"
```

I am getting this output.

```
> ./script.sh webserver wistudio
rajiv-webserver wistudio
```

But I am expecting this output.

```
rajiv-webserver rajiv-wistudio
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array initialization is wrong.  Change it to this:

```
services=($(echo $* | tr -d '/'))
```

Without the outer `()`, `services` would become a string and the parameter expansion `"${services[@]/#/$PREFIX-}"` adds `$PREFIX-` to your string.

In situations like this, `declare -p` can be used to examine the contents of your variable.  In this case, `declare -p services` should show you:

```
declare -a services=([0]="webserver" [1]="wistudio") # it is an array!
```

and not

```
declare -- services="webserver wistudio"             # it is a plain string
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. can you please also tell me why it was wrong? because echo "$services[@]" would still give me the values correctly

Comment: I would also like to know if consider it as a string then how would the solution work? in my another script i have to pass the appended value to a executable, Which accept only string.

Comment: May be create another question with the details.

Comment: `echo $*` still has many potential problems due to word splitting and wildcard expansion. I'd recommend using `services=("${@//\//}")` to create the array, since it'll work correctly with pretty much anything in the arguments.